# DirectX9 Multiple Video Card

Tags: direct3d, direct3d9

there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509330/c-directx-11-multiple-video-cards) about DirectX11, but DirectX9 is different.

The first parameter of IDirect3D9::CreateDevice and IDirect3D9Ex::CreateDevice is `UINT Adapter`, it should be a number between 0 and one less than the result of IDirect3D::GetAdapterCount

but the GetAdapterCount returns `1`, even my laptop have two video cards(one is Intel HD Graphics 3000, another is AMD HD7400M)

I can get the second video card by IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters in DirectX11, so how can i get to it in DirectX 9?

Comment: Use ``IDIrect3D::GetAdapterIdentifier`` to figure out which adapter in your system isn't enumerating, and then check those settings and drivers.

Comment: problem is that IDXGIFactory can enumerate all adapters correctly

Comment: Yes, but it's probably a driver or driver setting that keeping the Direct3D 9 device for one of your adapters hidden. The one that doesn't show up is the one that's hiding. You can also try ``DxCapsViewer`` in the Windows 8.x SDK (included with VS 2012 or VS 2013) or the legacy DirectX SDK to see if a device shows up under "DXGI Devices" but does not show up under "Direct3D 9 Devices". Also keep in mind that Direct3D 9 concept of an adapter is slightly different than DXGI: A single physical GPU with two monitors is 2 "adapters" in Direct3D 9, but a single "adapter" with 2 outputs in DXGI.

Comment: is it possible that two physical GPUs with one monitor is only one "adapters"(the second GPU is hidden) in Direct3D 9? I already set "High Performance" in AMD driver control center.

Comment: SLI/Crossfire rigs can be setup that way, yes.